# Span multiple columns with GridBagLayout | JAVA 8

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Is the following feasible with a Gridbaglayout? So that my headline has a columns width of 5 and all other elements a width of 1.

Wanted result:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                       HEADLINE                       | content0 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| content1 | content2 | content3 | content4 | content5 | content6 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Current state:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                       HEADLINE                       | content0 |
+------------------------------------------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| content1                                             | content2 | content3 | content4 | content5 | content6 |
+------------------------------------------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

When I set the gridwidth to 5 and 1: (remember to increase the gridx by 5...)

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|       HEA| content0 |DLINE                                      |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| content1 | content2 | content3 | content4 | content5 | content6 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: [Official Oracle tutorial on gridbaglayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you set the `gridwidth` of the `GridBagConstraints` for the headline to 5, and 1 for the others. (It being `GridBagLayout`, the sizes of `contentN` may vary.

Comment: worked partially but could you look into the new addition to my question. Why would be content0 intercept HEADLINE

Comment: @Georodin If HEADLINE is taking up five cells instead of one, the cell to the left should increment `gridx` by five instead of one. (I guess you were using `RELATIVE`, which I haven't found useful.)

Comment: yeah just found it out myself aswell, thank you very much
I have minor headache and not enough sleep - damn you netflix